# Javascript Regex to Validate only "sentence separated by comma"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate this string in javascript.

the availability on the second argument is restricted to R1, R2, R3, R4
the second and third argument can only be separated by comma, while the first and the second is by space.

```
req R1,1 //valid
req R2,3 //valid
req R0,1 //invalid
req R1 1 //invalid
```

I have written this:

```
/^req\sR1|R2|R3|R4[^,][0-9]+$/
```

but it fails on few cases:

```
req R3 1 //supposed to be invalid, valid using above regex
req R3.1 //supposed to be invalid, valid using above regex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the negated character class and this `R1|R2|R3|R4`. `R1|R2|R3|R4` won't do the thing you need. You need to put this into non-capturing group or capturing group  to make it to work . Like this `^req (?:R1|R2|R3|R4),\d+$` You could shorten this regex like the below

```
^req R[1-4],\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/8)

Comment: `\s` matches newline - boom.

Comment: if i use ` ` somebody will come and ask why don't you use the space character `\s`

Comment: that works, thanks! never realise actually you can do that simple.